# cannot connect to Minikube on MacOS

Tags: macos, kubernetes

I installed minikube as instructed here https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases
and started with with a simple `minikube start` command.

But the next step, which is as simple as `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` fails with

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout`

What did I miss?

Comment: You may not have set the context, cluster for kubectl to point to the minikube instance.

Comment: Nah, I tried it. It is setup correctly.

Comment: Which vm driver are you using? I just tried minikube with virtual box on OS X and it works fine. Can you visit 192.168.99.100:8443 via your web browser?

Comment: No the address is inaccessible. It works like a charm on my home computer, but no lock on the other one at work.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue using my Mac and basically I uninstalled both minikube and Kubectl and installed it as follows:

1. Installed Minikube.

curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.8.0/minikube-darwin-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/

2. Installed Kubectl.

curl -Lo kubectl http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.3.0/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl && sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/

3. Start a cluster, run the command:

minikube start

4. Minikube will also create a “minikube” context, and set it to default in kubectl. To switch back to this context later, run this command:

kubectl config use-context minikube

5. Now to get the list of all pods run the command:

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

Now you should be able to get the list of pods. Also make sure that you don't have a firewall within your network that blocks the connections.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue on win7 when changed work environment, as you said it is working fine at home but not working at office, high chance it caused by firewall policy, cannot pass TLS verification.

Instead of waste time on troubleshoot(sometimes nothing to do if you cannot turn off firewall), if you just want to test local minikube cluster, would suggest to disable TLS verification.

This is what I have done:

```
# How to disable minikube TLS verification 

## disable TLS verification 
$ VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 k8s-apiserver,tcp,127.0.0.1,8443,,8443
$ VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 k8s-dashboard,tcp,127.0.0.1,30000,,30000
$ kubectl config set-cluster minikube-vpn --server=https://127.0.0.1:8443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify
$ kubectl config set-context minikube-vpn --cluster=minikube-vpn --user=minikube
$ kubectl config use-context minikube-vpn

## test kubectl
$ kubectl get pods

## enable local docker client
$ VBoxManage controlvm minikube natpf1 k8s-docker,tcp,127.0.0.1,2374,,2376
$ eval $(minikube docker-env) 
$ unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
$ export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.1:2374"
$ alias docker='docker --tls' 

## test local docker client 
$ docker ps 

## test minikube dashboard
curl http://127.0.0.1:30000
```

Also I make a [small script](https://github.com/robertluwang/docker-hands-on-guide/blob/master/minikube-no-tls-verify.md) for this for your reference.

Hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just restart minikube. Sometimes I have this problem when my computer has been off for a while. I don't think you need to reinstall anything.

1. First verify you are in the correct context

   `$ kubectl config current-context
   minikube`
2. Check Minikube status (status should show "Running", mine below showed "Saved")

   `$ minikube status
   minikube: Saved
   cluster: 
   kubectl:`
3. Restart minikube

   `$ minikube start
   Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
   Starting VM...
   Getting VM IP address...
   Moving files into cluster...
   Setting up certs...
   Connecting to cluster...
   Setting up kubeconfig...
   Starting cluster components...
   Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.`
4. Verify it is running (This is what you should see)

   `$ minikube status
   minikube: Running
   cluster: Running
   kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when connected to Cisco AnyConnect VPN. Once I disconnected, minikube ran fine. Discussion on github here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4540